# Representing a grid in UML Class Diagram

Tags: class, uml, diagram, class-diagram

I would like to represent a grid for a timetable in a UML class diagram ahead of creating the software, but online resources make this confusing.

I know columns and rows (which is what I want) can be represented like this:

```
 MyClass
 + <<column>> Monday: String
 + <<column>> Tuesday: String
 + ...
 + <<row>> 9am: String
 + <<row>> 10am: String
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't act like a grid. From what I understand, this would treat the columns and rows seperately and not like coordinates: e.g. if I wanted to set something for Monday, 9am.

My question is, how could I go about doing this? Is there a step that I'm missing, or am I thinking about this in a completely wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to represent timetable by showing it hour by hour you should build your timetable as a (ordered) set of week days which in turns will be build of (ordered again) hours. In such case the diagram will look like that:

[image: Timetables with enumeration]

Moreover do not represent objects as parts of classes. Use another classes and if it's necessary mark it's multiplicity.

As a result you'll end up with 3 classes.

Note also that this is the simplest version. I would also recommend using some enumerators for names of DayOfWeek and for HourOfDay. Your diagram might look like that:

[image: Timetable - simple]

This is also with the approach that you specifically want to represent the presentation. It's definitely better to build the class for Activities and this part use only for GUI.

Comment: "Moreover do not represent objects as parts of classes"

Could you expand on this, sorry? I don't quite understand what you mean by this.

Comment: I'd suggest to use `<<enumeration>>` for DoW and HoD to fix Mo, Tu, We, etc.

Comment: As in, make dayName an enum instead of a string, @ThomasKilian ?

Comment: Yup, the usage of enumerators I've suggested in answer as well. I'll add another diagram representing this situation for clarification.

Comment: In your question you were suggesting adding the attributes "Monday", "Tuesday" ... etc. They actually represent specific objects. Instead you should have a collection of DayOfWeek with up to 7 elements in collection (or e.g. exactly 5 if you want to always represent working week). But on UML and code level it will be a collection (sequence to be specific) of elements of type DayOfWeek, yet on initiation you should create those 5 objects representing Monday, Tuesday etc. immediately. It is also possible to depict that in UML diagrams.

Comment: Awesome, great answer. Thanks for your help!